# Is there a way to continue doxygen lists across multiple comment blocks?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

Basically, I'm trying to do document code along the lines of:

```
//Description of Step 1
DoStep1_1();
DoStep1_2();
...
//Description of Step 2
DoStep2_1();
DoStep2_2();
```

I want the two comment blocks to turn into an ordered list in the Doxygen output. I've read the documentation on creating lists, and I understand that I can just use HTML tags, but it looks like there is extra stuff generated between to the tags that would be generated, that results in whitespace between the two items. Ultimately, I'd like to not have to use HTML tags; that is, I'd prefer to just use

```
/*!
  -# Description of Step 1
*/
DoStep1_1();
DoStep1_2();
...
/*!
  -# Description of Step 2
*/
DoStep2_1();
DoStep2_2();
```

or something along those lines. Is this even possible?

**EDIT:**
Okay, so I may not have described the results I'm getting and the results I want. The HTML generated from the above code is something like:

1. Description of Step 1

   Description of Step2

Note that there are 2 paragraph tags that I don't want, since they result in unwanted whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. I use it successfully. For more details, read my answer to that question: [How to be able to extract comments from inside a function in doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758045/how-to-be-able-to-extract-comments-from-inside-a-function-in-doxygen)

EDIT: After having read your actual and expected result

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to get rid off the whitespace between list elements.